# Sample DocuSign Connect XML document

Tags: docusignapi

Does anybody know if DocuSign provides sample xml docs that will be included in the request body for their Connect service?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A generic Connect packet is available here: https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/ndse-admin-guide-connect-technical-details

If you'd like to get a look of what one of *your* envelopes will look like, a free listener service like webhookapp.com can be used to capture a Connect publish.